# No reference parameter for bool function in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

So I was writing a program, and one of the functions is to determine whether the character is a vowel or not. The program is as follows:

```
bool is_vowel(string s)
{
    if (s == "A" || s == "a") return true;
    if (s == "E" || s == "e") return true;
    if (s == "I" || s == "i") return true;
    if (s == "O" || s == "o") return true;
    if (s == "U" || s == "u") return true;
    if (s == "Y" || s == "y") return true;

    return false;
}
```

So my question comes out when I tried to turn the string s into a reference parameter string& s. After the change, whenever I tried to call this function the program (I'm using Xcode on Mac btw) tells me `"No matching function for call to 'is_vowel'"`, even when the object inside IS a string object. So why can't I use a reference parameter here? Isn't the "s" referred to whichever string I use to call this function? I used reference parameters for most of the functions in which I'm not changing anything because I think referring instead of copying the value into a new parameter may be more efficient. So why it won't work here?
BTW, is it true that "referring instead of copying the value into a new parameter is more efficient"?

Edit: per the request of many, I'll just add one other function that calls this one; and for the purpose of simplicity, I've cut off a big chunk of the code. So don't dwell on logic of this part too much.

```
int FRI_Syllables(vector<string>& s)
{
    int syllables = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        string word = s[i];

        for (int n = 0; n < word.length(); n++)
        {
            if (is_vowel(word.substr(n, 1)))
                syllables ++; //Rule 1: count each vowel as a syllable
        }
    }

    return syllables;
}
```

And as for the change to the bool function, everything else is the same, except the first line is

```
bool is_vowel(string& s)
```

and the error Xcode gives me is "No matching function for call to 'is_vowel'".

Comment: First of all, you would want a const reference, secondly, show the code calling this function.

Comment: You've shown us code that works, and you're asking about code that doesn't work. Show us the code that doesn't work, along with the exact error message, and we can probably help.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to pass a plain old C style style. This is ok but invokes an implicit conversion to a temporary `std::string` (rvalue). Since it's an rvalue it must be passed by const-reference or by value.

Comment: You should really use the `Boost.Tribool` library, since Y should return `maybe`, not `true` or `false`. :)

Comment: @Steve I use this part mostly for counting syllables; and since I don't know the `Boost.Tribool` library (I'm quite new to C++ actually), I use a workaround later in the count syllable function. But thanks for the tip, I'll look into that library.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway for your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you would like to use const reference as opposed to reference when you do not change the value like in this particular case.

Secondly, string for a character is an overkill.

Thirdly, the code works just fine for me as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool is_vowel(const string &s)
{
    if (s == "A" || s == "a") return true;
    if (s == "E" || s == "e") return true;
    if (s == "I" || s == "i") return true;
    if (s == "O" || s == "o") return true;
    if (s == "U" || s == "u") return true;
    if (s == "Y" || s == "y") return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string mystring = "b";
    string mystring2 = "A";
    cout << is_vowel(mystring) << endl;
    cout << is_vowel(mystring2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can reproduce your issue if I just pass a string literal as follows:

> main.cpp:24:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘const char*’
>        cout << is_vowel("f") << endl;

If that is your case, this is another reason for using const reference instead of reference. You could use value semantics, too, but I agree with you about your reference conclusion.

Comment: Thanks, the addition of const works. So could you explain a little about the difference between a "regular" reference and a const reference?

Comment: Oh, and as for the string overkill comment, I did consider using char instead (would this be better?), but I kept using string just for consistency. So is string type more resource-consuming than char type?

Comment: A const reference means that the thing referred to cannot change, it's constant. When you use a string literal, that is const, you cannot pass it to a function expecting a non-const parameter.

Comment: Converting a string literal to `std::string` produces a non-const `std::string`. The problem is that a non-const reference cannot bind to this temporary string.

Comment: @OP, C++ has a rule that a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object. This rule exists to help avoid coding errors, because it is usually a mistake to try and do that. (A non-const reference implies you might want to modify the referred-to object, but if it is a temporary object then it will die immediately afterwards so those modifications will be lost).